# Changing User in TortoiseSVN

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn

We have an existing Tortoise svn environment that's been in use for a few years, password protected.

Unfortunately, our network admin deleted my user account and created a different one for me in Active Directory, so now I'm logging in to Windows as "User2" instead of "User1" used previously.

TortoiseSVN doesn't like this at all.  If I try to do anything interacting with the server and our existing code it fails.

Even just doing a simple "SVN Update" to get any code changes from the server results in an error that says:

"Access to C:\Users\User2 was denied".

It does this before even prompting me to enter my svn user/pwd (which haven't changed).

So apparently the Windows user/pwd is more important, or checked first I guess.

Now I'm stuck, unable to do anything with our code in svn.

I've tried looking through the Help and haven't found this scenario yet.

Is there a config file or registry key that I need to update to get svn working for my new user account?

Note, I didn't install or configure svn so I'm not real familiar with the setup, I've just used it at a user level.

My machine is Windows 7 and our svn server is Windows Server 2008 r2.  Thanks.

Comment: Do you just need to clear your authentication data so TSVN will prompt you again for it?  The button to do that is located [here](https://tortoisesvn.net/docs/nightly/TortoiseSVN_en/tsvn-dug-settings.html#tsvn-dug-settings-saved-data).

Comment: @PatrickQuirk - this is **real answer**, not comment

Comment: @LazyBadger I didn't fully follow the question so I wasn't really sure. Thanks for expanding on it though!

Answer (score 4):

Slightly expanded version of Patrick's answer

- If it wasn't disabled in configuration by hand (`%APPDATA%\Subversion\config`, `store-auth-creds` key in `[auth]` section), Subversion (and TortoiseSVN as Subversion client) stores all used credentials (per realm) and use *stored* credentials later without interaction to user
- In order to re-authorize to previously used realm, you have to remove old data
- As Patrick noted, the easiest way is to use internal TortoiseSVN possibilities (`TortoiseSVN` - `Settings` - `Saved Data` - `Authentication data`)

> If you want to clear authentication data for one particular server
>   only, use the Clear... instead of the Clear all button.

[image: Clean window]

(can't imagine, that is and how and when I got `svn.username` records, but `svn.simple` are my accessed repositories with `AuthType Basic`), but you can perform such cleanup by hand: all `svn.simple` records stored in `%APPDATA%\Subversion\auth\svn.simple` in separate files (file per realm) and realms aren't encoded, `svn:realmstring` contain URL and name of realm, thus: you can delete any this file as ordinary file on FS

```
K 8
passtype
V 8
wincrypt
K 8
password
V 260
AQAAANCMnd8BFdERjH...=
K 15
svn:realmstring
V 61
<http://websvn.tigris.org:80> CollabNet Subversion Repository
K 8
username
V 5
guest
END
```

Comment: I can't use the interface to clear anything out because the button is grayed out.

I looked in svn.simple and there was one file there, which I removed. But that didn't change anything, it still fails with the same message as before.

svn.username is empty.

P.S. I found this stuff under my old username. Under the new one the directories are all empty, which is no surprise since I'm not able to use Tortoise svn yet under this new user.

Answer (score 3):

The error message `"Access to C:\Users\User2 was denied"` indicates that your problem has nothing to do with svn authentication or authentication with the repository.

The problem is that you don't have full write access to the folder on your harddrive `C:\Users\User2` where I assume your working copy is located.

When updating a working copy, svn must have full access to the working copy folder and all files within - not just write access but also the permissions to change access rights.

Comment: I don't have a working copy because I can't connect to svn.  And I do have full control of that directory. My user is a local Administrator and a domain administrator.  I just created a text file in that directory and deleted it.  So it's not a Windows permissions issue. I think the TortoiseSVN message may be a little misleading.